# Iterating through all nodes in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to iterate through all nodes in an XML file and print their names.
What is the best way to do this? I am using .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think the fastest and simplest way would be to use an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8a5e1s5(v=VS.100).aspx), this will not require any recursion and minimal memory foot print.

Here is a simple example, for compactness I just used a simple string of course you can use a stream from a file etc.

```
  string xml = @"
    <parent>
      <child>
        <nested />
      </child>
      <child>
        <other>
        </other>
      </child>
    </parent>
    ";

  XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName);
    }
  }
```

The result of the above will be

```
parent
child
nested
child
other
```

A list of all the elements in the XML document.

Answer (score 61):

You can use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). Also some XPath can be useful.

Just a simple example

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("sample.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("some_node"); // You can also use XPath here
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   // use node variable here for your beeds
}
```

Comment: Prefer this because it treats the start/end elements and content as a single item, compared to using XmlReader

Comment: not sure why foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) only loop thru 1 top node such as ("some_node") and does not get to nested children node below it and etc ... in the (XmlNodeList nodes). Can you please help?

Answer (score 21):

This is what I quickly wrote for myself:

```
public static class XmlDocumentExtensions
{
    public static void IterateThroughAllNodes(
        this XmlDocument doc, 
        Action<XmlNode> elementVisitor)
    {
        if (doc != null && elementVisitor != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
            {
                doIterateNode(node, elementVisitor);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void doIterateNode(
        XmlNode node, 
        Action<XmlNode> elementVisitor)
    {
        elementVisitor(node);

        foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            doIterateNode(childNode, elementVisitor);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, I've used something like:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(somePath);

doc.IterateThroughAllNodes(
    delegate(XmlNode node)
    {
        // ...Do something with the node...
    });
```

Maybe it helps someone out there.

Comment: This is great! I learned a ton by stepping through this code, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Generalized approach. +1 I prefer this one.

Answer (score 14):

To iterate through all elements

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants())
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
}
```

Comment: prefer using this over `XmlDocument`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument (even older than this question here)

Answer (score 4):

A recursive algorithm that parses through an `XmlDocument`

Here is an example - [Recursively reading an xml document and using regex to get contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825459/recursively-reading-an-xml-document-and-using-regex-to-get-contents)

Here is another recursive example - [http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/LoopThroughXmlDocumentRecursively.html](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/LoopThroughXmlDocumentRecursively.htm)