# Get reference tags child of an XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clientes>
    <cliente>
        <nome>Cliente1</nome>
        <contatos>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato1</nome>
            </contato>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato2</nome>
            </contato>
        </contatos>
    </cliente>  
    <cliente>
        <nome>Cliente2</nome>
        <contatos>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato3</nome>
            </contato>
            <contato>
                <nome>Contato4</nome>
            </contato>
        </contatos>
    </cliente>
</clientes>
```

I must saved in database in two tables, the CLIENTE and his CONTATOS, but I can only take each TAG at once and they do not have reference being thus:

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   ds.ReadXml("c:\xmlfile.xml");

   ds.Tables[0];
   //Here can get CLIENTES
   ds.Tables[1];
   //Here can get CONTATOS
```

That I can not create references , the foreign key for CLIENTE x CONTATOS , because I have no CONTATO which is related to that CLIENTE.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your choice to read the xml into a dataset.  You're losing the association between Cliente and Contatos by using a dataset.  Here are some ideas:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915294/iterating-through-all-nodes-in-xml-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to process the XML is using XElement.
If the actual XML document is in a much more complex namespace than the example shown, then just be aware the XElement doesn't play that well with namespaces.

However, if it's a very simple XML Schema as above,

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("c:\xmlfile.xml");

foreach (XElement element in elementsInDoc)
    Console.WriteLine(element);  // or add to database

foreach(XElement client in doc.Elements("cliente"))
{
     foreach(XElement contato in client.Elements("contato"))
     {
          //add name to database
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without a common field between the objects. When you think about how they are persisted in the database you'd need a column in both tables to create the relation.

If you have a chance to manipulate the XML you can solve the issue by adding a common column and relation.

Sample XML:

```
<clientes>
    <cliente id="1">
        <nome>Cliente1</nome>
        <contatos>
            <contato cliente_id="1">
                <nome>Contato1</nome>
            </contato>
            <contato cliente_id="1">
                <nome>Contato2</nome>
            </contato>
        </contatos>
    </cliente>  
    <cliente id="2">
        <nome>Cliente2</nome>
        <contatos>
            <contato cliente_id="2">
                <nome>Contato3</nome>
            </contato>
            <contato cliente_id="2">
                <nome>Contato4</nome>
            </contato>
        </contatos>
    </cliente>
</clientes>
```

and the relation:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"xmlfile1.xml");

ds.Relations.Add(
    "cliente-contato-rel", 
    ds.Tables["cliente"].Columns["id"],
    ds.Tables["contato"].Columns["cliente_id"]);
```

After establishing the relation you can access the child/parent rows over that such as:

```
ds.Tables["contato"].Rows[3].GetParentRow("cliente-contato-rel").ItemArray
```

would return

```
{object[3]}
    [0]: "Cliente2"
    [1]: 1
    [2]: "2"
```

Comment: I can not manipulate the XML, it is another company. But your idea will be use in another code here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You could design the tables in Excel to you can see the results easily.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                    "<clientes>" +
                        "<cliente>" +
                            "<nome>Cliente1</nome>" +
                            "<contatos>" +
                                "<contato>" +
                                    "<nome>Contato1</nome>" +
                                "</contato>" +
                                "<contato>" +
                                    "<nome>Contato2</nome>" +
                                "</contato>" +
                            "</contatos>" +
                        "</cliente>" +
                        "<cliente>" +
                            "<nome>Cliente2</nome>" +
                            "<contatos>" +
                                "<contato>" +
                                    "<nome>Contato3</nome>" +
                                "</contato>" +
                                "<contato>" +
                                    "<nome>Contato4</nome>" +
                                "</contato>" +
                            "</contatos>" +
                        "</cliente>" +
                    "</clientes>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //ds.ReadXml("c:\xmlfile.xml");
            ds.Tables.Add("CLIENTES");
            DataTable dtClientes = ds.Tables["CLIENTES"];
            dtClientes.Columns.Add("CLIENTES", typeof(string));

            ds.Tables.Add("CONTATOS");
            DataTable dtContatos = ds.Tables["CONTATOS"];
            dtContatos.Columns.Add("CLIENTES", typeof(string));
            dtContatos.Columns.Add("CONTATOS", typeof(string));

            var clientes = doc.Descendants("cliente").Select(x => new {
                nome = x.Element("nome").Value,
                contatos = x.Descendants("contato").Select(y => y.Element("nome").Value).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var cliente in clientes)
            {
                dtClientes.Rows.Add(new object[] { cliente.nome });
                foreach (var contato in cliente.contatos)
                {
                    dtContatos.Rows.Add(new object[] { cliente.nome, contato });
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```