# How to retrieve element values of nested elements in XML with C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<config>
<timeDifferenceFields>
    <TimeDifference>
        <StartTimeField>txt_SoReinigungUhrzeitvonZ1</StartTimeField>
        <EndTimeField>txt_SoReinigungUhrzeitbisZ1</EndTimeField>
        <OutputTimeField>txt_SoReinigungZ1</OutputTimeField>
    </TimeDifference>
    <TimeDifference>
        <StartTimeField>txt_SoReinigungUhrzeitvonZ2</StartTimeField>
        <EndTimeField>txt_SoReinigungUhrzeitbisZ2</EndTimeField>
        <OutputTimeField>txt_SoReinigungZ2</OutputTimeField>
    </TimeDifference>
    <TimeDifference>
        <StartTimeField>txt_SoReinigungUhrzeitvonZ3</StartTimeField>
        <EndTimeField>txt_SoReinigungUhrzeitbisZ3</EndTimeField>
        <OutputTimeField>txt_SoReinigungZ3</OutputTimeField>
    </TimeDifference>
</timeDifferenceFields>
</config>
```

Hi,

can someone help me with this easy task, I dont get it...

I want to iterate over the TimeDifference-Fields in the above XML-File. For each TimeDifference Node I want to call a method with the given XML-Values.

With this it runs into a NPE ... can someone help please

```
     XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument();
        configDoc.Load(configXml);

        XmlNode timeFields = configDoc.SelectSingleNode("/config/timeDifferenceFields/TimeDifference");
        foreach (XmlNode timeNode in timeFields)
        {
        String OutputTimeField = timeNode.SelectSingleNode("OutputTimeField").InnerXml;
        String StartTimeField = timeNode.SelectSingleNode("StartTimeField").InnerXml;
        String EndTimeField = timeNode.SelectSingleNode("EndTimeField").InnerXml;
        addTimeDiffElement(inputDoc, OutputTimeField, StartTimeField, EndTimeField);
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825459/recursively-reading-an-xml-document-and-using-regex-to-get-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectSingleNode` returns (as the name suggests) not more than one node. Try XmlNodeList `timeFields = configDoc.SelectNodes("/config/timeDifferenceFields/TimeDifference")` instead.